# Using WEKA classifier model in Java for classifying real time text

Tags: java, nlp, weka

I had used the GUI to train a classifier for some sample arff files . After training I saved the obtained model  .

Now that I need to use this model file in my java code to classify some text , could you please tell me how should I proceed ? I dont want to do an evaluation but would like to classify the input text given .

I had gone thru the http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization & http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code .

But still couldn't find code for it .I just got an way to load a model file .But didn't get any clue on classifying text directly to classes .  Any help on this regard would be helpfull .

Answer (score 2):

Although the previously suggested post is very nice, I believe that the one I produced some time ago better fits your needs, as it specifically *deals with text*, and it is generic regarding the classifier. Please check "[A Simple Text Classifier in Java with WEKA](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/a-simple-text-classifier-in-java-with.html)".

Answer (score 2):

See here, similar tutorial by Hidalgo - Java code with slides and textual dataset. It trains a machine, loads the model and classify real time unseen textual data. Very easy to follow
https://github.com/drelhaj/MachineLearning